# How do I connect 3 audio inputs with a switch?

Tags: audio, switches, wiring

I have 3 outputs from different audio sources via aux cable. I'm trying to combine them all into a box and have an easy way to change the audio source. If only one source is going to be used at a time how should I wire everything together?

Should I use a 3 position slide switch like this?

http://www.allelectronics.com/make-a-store/item/ssw-62/on-on-on-3-position-slide-switch/1.html

Or can I just wire them all together without a switch. Would there be interference that way since only 1 of the 3 audio sources will be on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need something like that but if you have stereo signals you need a 2 pole three way switch.

There will be two common pins you put one to the left input of the amplifier and one to the right input.

It will be similar to the schematic below (I could only find a 2 pole double throw switch but it will be similar for a 3 way but with more inputs).

The grounds for all the inputs and outputs are all connected together.

For the switch you may find a rotary switch is more easily available and easier to mount as it only needs a round hole in a panel.

For example:[image]
[Two pole 3 way switch](http://www.parts-express.com/parts-express-rotary-switch-2-pole-6-position-non-shorting--023-664?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=pla)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fDhloQ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Do not wire them all together. Connecting these outputs to each other may result in damage to one of the devices. You could connect all of them with resistors forming a summing junction. Or you could use a selector switch like the one you mention. Just note that you may need a multiple pole version.

If you are not looking for a project there probably exists a packaged solution to this task.

Comment: would something like this work? or does it degrade quality? http://www.amazon.com/CablesOnline-3-Rings-Splitter-Gold-Plated-AV-Y01F4/dp/B00AUVSYBG

Comment: No, that is intended to connect multiple inputs to a single device's output. Therefore you would still risk damage to the devices.

Comment: ok so if i got a dp3t slide switch. I would have the Right on a pole and the Left on a pole and all the grounds connected together? or do I need a third pole for the ground?

Comment: Connect all the grounds directly together, you don't need another switch pole.

Comment: As long as the grounds are not connected elsewhere in the system. You don't want to create a ground loop.